# Is there a way to select a value which matches partially?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, consider:

```
title 1: The Indiana Highway project
title 2: The Michigan Highway project
```

Now when the user enters `Highway` in the form box both the titles need to be displayed.
If the user enters `Michigan`, only one title (title 2) needs to be displayed.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL or PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're always searching only for one word, you can use the `LIKE` keyword.

```
SELECT someField, anotherField, FROM table WHERE aField LIKE '%Highway%'
```

The `%`s are wildcards saying that any characters (or none) can be to the left and to the right of Highway.

[See documentation here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

If you plan on doing something more sofisticated, take a look at [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use the LIKE operator in MySQL to select values by partial match.

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%Highway%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE title LIKE '%Highway%'
```

That should do the trick. Something like that will bring back every result where the title has the word Highway somewhere inside

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL provides LIKE:

```
WHERE anonymous_column LIKE '%Highway%'
```

There are other more complicated regular expression operations too, but that would suffice for your immediate purposes.